# How to do an accent-insensitive TrigramSimilarity search in django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-postgresql

How can I add accent-insensitive search to following snippet from the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigramsimilarity):

```
>>> from django.contrib.postgres.search import TrigramSimilarity
>>> Author.objects.create(name='Katy Stevens')
>>> Author.objects.create(name='Stephen Keats')
>>> test = 'Katie Stephens'
>>> Author.objects.annotate(
...     similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name', test),
... ).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
[<Author: Katy Stevens>, <Author: Stephen Keats>]
```

How could this match `test = 'Kâtié Stéphèns'`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There exist the [unaccent](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#unaccent) lookup:

> The [unaccent](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#unaccent) lookup allows you to perform accent-insensitive lookups using a dedicated PostgreSQL extension.

Also if you take a look at the [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates) part of django docs, you can read the following:

> When specifying the field to be aggregated in an aggregate function,
>   **Django will allow you to use the same double underscore notation that
>   is used when referring to related fields in filters.** Django will then
>   handle any table joins that are required to retrieve and aggregate the
>   related value.

---

**Derived from the above:**

You can use the [`trigram_similar`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#trigram-similarity) lookup, combined with `unaccent`, then `annotate` on the result:

```
Author.objects.filter(
    name__unaccent__trigram_similar=test
).annotate(
    similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name__unaccent', test),
).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
```

*OR*

if you want to keep it as close as possible to the original sample (and omit one potentially slow filtering followed by another):

```
Author.objects.annotate(
    similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name__unaccent', test),
).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
```

**Those will only work in Django version >= 1.10**

---

**EDIT:**

Although the above should work, @Private reports this error occurred:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'unaccent' into a field. Join on 'unaccented' not permitted.
```

This may be a bug, or `unaccent` is not intended to work that way. The following code works without the error:

```
Author.objects.filter(
    name__unaccent__trigram_similar=test
).annotate(
    similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name', test),
).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
```

Comment: That makes sense, but could you show me how to use that in the sample code in my question?

Comment: Thanks, the example in the docs, however, does not start with filter, but with annotate:   `objects.annotate(
...     similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name', test),
... ).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')`

Comment: Yes but the example on the docs is general, and your problem is more specific, the code sample I provided above, does what you want!

Comment: Not completely: this only works in one way. If you have a search that is unaccented, it will not find its accented relatives.

Comment: To be more precise: `'name'` is used in the similarity scoring, but not in its unaccented form.

Comment: you can use lookups inside `TrigramSimilarity`'s expression as well, have a look at my edit

Comment: That gives me: `Cannot resolve keyword 'unaccent' into field. Join on 'unaccented' not permitted.`

Comment: Have you followed the `unaccent` activation instructions on this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#unaccent ?

Comment: I have. It seems this is a bug?

Comment: Or it is not intended to work this way. you can report it and let me know as well, it seems interesting! I will edit my answer with the initial code that "mostly" works.

Comment: Hey, @Private I am doing a pass through my answers and I was wondering about any news on the subject... Was my answer helpful?

Comment: To be honest I don't remember. I don't think your answer solved it completely, but it did put me on the right track. I'll accept.

Comment: digging deeper into the actual numbers. Your edit seems correct superficially, but it's actually just filtering without accents and then doing the similarity with accents again (which is wrong). Going to post the right answer...

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful to someone, solutions above didn't work for me.

I had to do this:

```
from django.db.models import Transform
from django.contrib.postgres.search import TrigramSimilarity

class Unaccent2(Transform):
   function = "UNACCENT"
   lookup_name = "unaccent"

def remove_accents(input_str):
   nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
   only_ascii = nfkd_form.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
   return only_ascii.decode()

qs = Author.objects.annotate(similarity=TrigramSimilarity(Unaccent2('name'), remove_accents(q))
qs = qs.filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unaccent extension + trigram similarity extension (both can be installed in postgres by running a migration, see:

https://stevenwithph.medium.com/installing-postgres-extensions-with-django-migration-files-462669984bc5

Then:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import TrigramSimilarity
from django.contrib.postgres.lookups import Unaccent

Author.objects.annotate(
    similarity=TrigramSimilarity(Unaccent('name'), test),
).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
```

Notice that when doing an unaccent on the right side of the `annotate()`, use the function rather than the `__unaccent` notation.